# Vanilla Javascript remove Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have a `render()` function, and inside of it there's this `sleep()` function:

```
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

(Using this inside an async function)

On the first run, everything is fine, but when I click on the new game button (which calls `render()`) a new `Promise` is created, but the previous one is still there too. So the `sleep()` counts time double.

I've read the MDN documentation and some stackoverflow questions, but didn't find the answer for this.

Can someone explain me how `Promise` actually works, and what have I done wrong?

EDIT:
When the game is finished and click on New Game button, everything seems fine except timer, which is counts seconds twice.
The code:

```
const render = () => {
  const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  const timerOnePlayer = async () => {
     timer.innerHTML = 0;
     timerText.innerHTML = "Eltelt idő";
     while (!gameFinished) {
       await sleep(1000);
       timer.innerHTML = Number(timer.innerHTML) + 1;
     }
  }
/** Some other irrelevant code*/
}

const resetValues = () => {
   /** variables set to zero or empty */
   render();
}

btnStart.addEventListener("click",render);
newGame.addEventListener("click",resetValues);
```

Comment: Every time you call that line of code, a new promise + timeout is created. This is not unique to promises. If you run a line of code twice, it runs twice. I think your question is not about promises or setTimeout, it's about how they work with react rendering.

Comment: It's inside a function, which return's at the end of the game. I think (maybe it's wrong) if the function returns, every variable and everything what I created inside it, will removed by default. At least in Java it worked like this. So I think the problem is either with `Promise` or `async`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code in the first place? It seems like `const sleep = (ms,resolve) => setTimeout(resolve,ms);` would allow you to wait a certain amount of time then run the callback function. Or just calling setTimeout without wrapping it up.

Comment: Your version of sleep is better, I didn't know it works this way. And the usage of this funcion: `const timerOnePlayer = async () => { /** ... */ while (!gameFinished) {await sleep(1000); } /** ... */};`. Sorry for the editing.

Comment: Please show us your actual code for the function and then describe in terms of that actual code what the problem is.

Comment: @jfriend00 Updated question with the actual code snippet.

Comment: This type of function is only meant to be called once.  You will need to either only call it once, detect it's already running when it's called more than once and do nothing on the subsequent calls, detect it's already running and cancel the previous invocation when it's called again or change the design entirely so you don't have this issue.

Comment: basically I tried to cancel the previous invocation, but don't know how to properly do it.

Comment: @GergőNagy the assumption of 'everything gets cleaned up' is not true. Things only get cleaned up if they are no longer referenced. A callback based on a timeout will only get garbage collected after it's ran, or if you used `clearTimeout`

Comment: Thanks for this information, and thanks for all comments, now I changed the code like you told me, and now it's working fine!

Answer (score 0):

When I started this project didn't really know how `Promise` or `setIntervall` works. But with the comments, I figured out what's wrong, removed `sleep()` from the project and replaced with just `setIntervall`. Now everything works fine, so thanks again!

```
const timerOnePlayer = () => {
    timer.innerHTML = 0;
    timerText.innerHTML = "Eltelt idő";
    onePlayerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      timer.innerHTML = Number(timer.innerHTML) + 1;
      if (gameFinished) clearInterval(onePlayerInterval);
    }, 1000);
  };
```